# NGXS using an Observable output to dispatch actions

Tags: angular, ngxs

In the case where I have an observable that could periodically emit new values (Timer, SignalR, etc), is there a better way to dispatch NGXS actions besides calling `store.dispatch()` from the `.subscribe` method on the observable?

I like to avoid outright subscribing to observables when possible (especially in services that may be in lazy loaded feature modules), preferring the `async` pipe in templates.

*Edit for clarity*

What I really want to do is automatically dispatch an action based on the output of an observable without having to explicitly subscribe to that observable - I'd like the ngxs framework to handle that subscription.

So instead of doing something like:

```
    let mySubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(val => { 
        this.store.dispatch(new SomeAction());
    });
```

I would like to do something like:

```
    fromSource(interval(1000)).dispatch(val => new SomeAction());
```

where the framework handles the subscription.  This is purely a nice to have feature that I've seen in other state management libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in your service like.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Dispatch } from '@ngxs-labs/dispatch-decorator';
import { MyAction } from './my.actions';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  @Dispatch()
  myObservable() {
    // Replace with your observable that periodically emits new values
    return interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(new MyAction()));
  }
}
```

You can then use this method in your component by calling it and using the async pipe:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="(myService.myObservable() | async) as result">
      {{ result }}
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(public myService: MyService) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't do what I'm looking for.  I believe the intent of the dispatch-decorator is so you don't have to inject the store into controllers/services that you may dispatch from.  I'll edit my post to make what I'm looking to do more clear.